# Filling gaps in DATE fiel

Tags: sql, postgresql, tableau-api

I am querying a DATE field:

```
SELECT  DATE  ,
    FIELD2 ,
    FIELD3 
into Table_new
FROM    Table_old
WHERE (criteria iLIKE '%xxxyyy%')
```

The DATE field runs from 10/1/2010 to present, but it has missing days along the way.  When I export the data (in Tableau, for example), I need the data to line up with a calendar that DOES NOT have any missing dates.  This means I need a space/holder for a date, even if no data exists for that date in the query.  How can I achieve this?

Right now I am exporting the data, and manually creating a space where no data for a date exists, which is extremely inefficient.

Comment: What do you mean by _space holder_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tableau can do this natively. No need to alter your data set. You just need to make sure that your `DATE` field is of the date type in Tableau and then show emptycolumns/rows.

---

My test data:

[image]

Before I show empty columns:

[image]

How I show empty columns:

[image]

After I show empty columns (end result):

[image]

---

If you want to then restrict those dates, you can add the date field to the filter, select your date range, and `Apply to Context`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can easily generate the dates:

```
select mm.date, t.field1, t.field2
from (select generate_series(mm.mindate, mm.maxdate, interval '1 day') as date
      from (select min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
            from table_old
            where criteria ilike '%xxxyyy%'
           ) mm
     ) d left join
     table_old t
     on t.date = mm.date and
        criteria ilike '%xxxyyy%';
```

This returns all dates between the minimum and maximum for the criteria.  If you have another date range in mind, just use that for the `generate_series()`.

Note:  The final condition on `criteria` needs to go in the `on` clause not a `where` clause.

Comment: Any other DBMS supports something like that?? Seems so efficient.

Comment: Seems convoluted.  Is there a simpler/more elegant solution?

Comment: @ZJAY Trust me, generating dates is usually 10 times less elegant then that!

Comment: Do I actually have to specify the min/max date in this answer, or does the logic detect it automatically?  Thanks

Comment: I'm simply trying to enter an empty space on dates that have no values in a specified range.

Comment: @ZJAY . . . You can put arbitrary dates in the `generate_series()`.  Your question made it sound like you wanted the minimum and maximum.